# Is there any js function to run a script after ajax load of content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sugarcrm

There are more than 2 questions about "How to run a js after Ajax load of content". They all suggest to run JS after Ajax load completed. I know how to handle that.

Suppose more than 40 pages load a page `my-Page.php` via Ajax. Is there any JS function like `$(document).ready` to handle running the script after Ajax load of content?

Please note that editing more than 40 files is not rational.

A little bit more about my problem:

I am customizing sugar crm to use jquery ui date picker instead of its simple JS calendar. calling `$('#inp').datepicker()` in a Ajax call fails, because there is no `$(#inp)` object available.

> works

```
Calendar.setup ({ldelim}
         inputField : "{{$idname}}",
         ifFormat : "{$CALENDAR_FORMAT}",
         daFormat : "{$CALENDAR_FORMAT}",
         button : "{{$idname}}_trigger",
         singleClick : true,
         dateStr : "{$date_value}",
         step : 1,
         weekNumbers:false  {rdelim}    );
```

---

> `doesn't work`

```
 jQuery(function() {ldelim}
                      jQuery('#{{$idname}}_hpm').datepicker({ldelim}
                          showOn: 'button',
                          buttonImage: 'include/jdp/styles/images/calendar.png',
                          buttonImageOnly: true,
                          changeMonth: true,
                          changeYear: true,
                          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'
                      {rdelim});
                  {rdelim});
```

I wonder how it's basic `Calendar.setup()` works, but my script.

Comment: I would hope you have only one common function for loading ajax content that is used in all 40 files?

Comment: "Please note that editing more than 40 files is not rational."  Wow.

Comment: For sure there are may be one common function, but this function serves many other Ajax requests. nice comment @Brad, but is there any function available?

Comment: @HPM: What if you add a `callback` parameter to that "common function"?  Pass it a function that calls `$('#inp').datepicker()`, and run it when the AJAX call is done.

Comment: @HPM: And what function do you use? Please show it to us.

Comment: That's OK @ Rocket Hazmat, if you are sure there is no $(document-ajax).complete available in js, please let me know.

Comment: @HPM: What do you mean by `$(document-ajax).complete`?  There's a method when the AJAX method completes.  It's called a callback.  Either `$.ajax({url: '', success: function(){ //callback }});`  or `$.get('url', function(data){ //callback });`.

Comment: No I mean suppose there is no way to edit other pages and the only script you can edit is the one that ajax calls. Is there any way to run a script in the called page?

Comment: @HPM: Yes.  The way I just said.  Using the AJAX callbacks.

Comment: But Ajax call backs exist in an other page. Suppose I just have access to my-Page.php `please read second paragraph of question`

Comment: @HPM: Oh, so you want to edit the page being loaded via AJAX.  Sorry, that was not very clear.  (Also, you said there was a "common" AJAX function).  Anyway, in that case, you can try to add a `$(document).ready` inside your `my-Page.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into this issue too. The solution is hinted at [here](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/09/30/improving-sugarcrm-client-side-performance-the-sugarcrm-ajaxui/).

Since SugarCRM comes with the YUI library you can use the `onContentReady` function.

```
var yourFunction = function(){
    console.log("Hello world! #myElementId is loaded!")
};
YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady('myElementId',yourFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'success' section of the AJAX call that will run any function inside of it:

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
          url : 'example.org',
          dataType : 'json',
          data:   {   id:'33d',
        },
        success : function(data){
          //Add function here
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // Add error functions here
        });
        return false;
      });
```

I dont know if that is what you are looking for though.